# Android Studio: Lock Screen Notification click Show Activity and Unlock Phone

Tags: android, screen

I have a Lock Screen Notification that must call an Activity unlock the device.

I have tried addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD) this make the activity shows but lock screen continues.

I also tried lock.disableKeyguard(); it is deprecate and also I cant, for some android reason, reenable it.

The Code for Calling the Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(APP.getINSTANCE(), MainActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Anyone, any idea on how to make this "absurd extraordinary thing" on the "marvelous" android?

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
//                DftOp.getActivity().setShowWhenLocked(true);
                DftOp.getActivity().setTurnScreenOn(true);
                KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)  DftOp.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
                if(keyguardManager!=null)
                    keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(DftOp.getActivity(), null);
            } else {
                DftOp.getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
//                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            }
```